# How to refresh the angular content after changing the active bootstrap tab?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a component that shows several tabs but depending on the logic of the business it will be active one or the other, something like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li *ngIf="activateTab1" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">
      <span class="fa fa-home fa-lg color-blue "></span> tab1</a></li>
    <li *ngIf="!activateTab1"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">
      <span class="fa fa-home fa-lg color-blue "></span> tab1</a></li>

    <li *ngIf="activateTab2" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">
      <span class="fa fa-home fa-lg color-blue "></span> tab2</a></li>
    <li *ngIf="!activateTab2"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">
      <span class="fa fa-home fa-lg color-blue "></span> tab1</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <app-component-tab1></app-component-tab1>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <app-component-tab2></app-component-tab2>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this code the tab is activated correctly but the content of the tab (which is an angular component) is not recharged. I think it may be because the tab is not being clicked and the "href" is not called. So how could I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can go for [**Dynamic tabs**](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tabs) by ngx-botstrap

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since I still had the opportunity to select libraries, I ended up using PrimeNG's p-tabView (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/). In this way the task is simplified and the development is more focused on Angular. It would be something like this:

```
 <p-tabView>
    <p-tabPanel header="tab1" leftIcon="fa-home" [selected]="activateTab1">
      <app-component-tab1></app-component-tab1>
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="tab2" leftIcon="fa-home" [selected]="activateTab2">
      <app-component-tab2></app-component-tab2>
    </p-tabPanel>
  </p-tabView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use ngIf? **ngClass** is better in this case. You should use class="active" for tab-pane as well.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li [ngClass]="{'active': activateTab1}">
        <a data- toggle="tab" href="#tab1">
            <span class="fa fa-home fa-lg color-blue "></span>tab1
        </a>
    </li>

    <li [ngClass]="{'active': !activateTab1}">
        <a data- toggle="tab" href="#tab2">
            <span class="fa fa-home fa-lg color-blue "></span>tab2
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade" [ngClass]="{'active': activateTab1}">
        <app-component-tab1></app-component-tab1>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade" [ngClass]="{'active': !activateTab1}">
        <app-component-tab2></app-component-tab2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: generally speaking, it's not a good idea to mix Jquery in the angular world unless necessary.  This is not one of those case where it would be necessary

Answer (score 0):

This is an Angular/CSS based solution. You will need to fill in your CSS to look like you want.

I use classes and CSS to hide and show the content sections and to show the tabs at the top.
I use Angular to change which tab is being viewed. That, in turn, changes the `class` value on the outermost `<div>` which is what makes the CSS work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Example</title>
    <style>
    .nav-tabs {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
      list-style: none;
    }
    .tab {
      background-color: #ddd;
      border: 1px solid #999;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 0 -1px 0;
      padding: 4px 8px;
    }

    .active-tab1 .tab1,
    .active-tab2 .tab2 {
      background-color: white;
      border-bottom-color: white;
    }

    .tab-content {
      display: none;
    }

    .active-tab1 .tab-content1,
    .active-tab2 .tab-content2 {
      display: block;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

    myApp.controller('appController', function($scope) {
      $scope.activeTab = 1;

      $scope.changeTabs = function(tab) {
        $scope.activeTab = tab;
        return false;
      }
    });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="appController">
    <div class="active-tab{{activeTab}}">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="tab tab1"><a ng-click="changeTabs(1)">tab1</a></li>
        <li class="tab tab2"><a ng-click="changeTabs(2)">tab2</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div>
        <div class="tab-content tab-content1" class="tab-pane fade">
          <p>This is the Tab 1 content</p>
          <app-component-tab1></app-component-tab1>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content tab-content2" class="tab-pane fade">
          <p>This is the Tab 2 content</p>
          <app-component-tab2></app-component-tab2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: He is using angular 2+

Comment: Sorry, I have not played with Angular2. But the login should work in 2 just as much as any other. The idea is to allow CSS to do all the hard work at compile time speeds and let Angular do as little as possible at script speeds.

Comment: Yes, the browser uses compiled code to process CSS. One CSS change will always be faster then multiple changes and much faster then adding or removing DOM.